# $scope.$watch is not capturing the changed values of the global variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

In HTML

```
<div id="myMessage" value="{{myMessage}}" ng-model="myMessage">

<script>
    var myMessage ;
    function showMessage(message) {
                console.log("message type is" +message.type);
                myMessage = message ;
    }
</script>
```

There is always a web socket or ajax call to keep getting the vaues of message argument in the function showMessage. So, the value of global variable myMessage also keeps on changing but it is not getting reflected in the controller watch function.

In Controller.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
myApp.controller('executeController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.myMessage;
$scope.myMessage = document.getElementById('myMessage').value;

$scope.$watch('myMessage' , function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log("myMessage in controller" +$scope.myMessage);
})
```

I cannot transfer the code from html script tag to controller. But need the value of message argument which keeps on changing in the controller file. What i am doing wrong ? Please help ..

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope.myMessage` in your controller  is different from `var myMessage` in your "script" part.

The `$scope.$watch('myMessage'..)` watch the variable in the scope not the one in the "script" part.

The following line is runned only one time, on the controller first execution so the watch will never get a new value :

```
 $scope.myMessage = document.getElementById('myMessage').value;
```

Why you don't make your AJAX call in the controller ?

Comment: @Alainlb  I cannot make that call in the controller. Yes, it is getting called only once. I have to access the value of message in controller and catch its changing values as well . How should i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert `myMessage` to a function and watch that function:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('executeController', function($scope, $http) {
    var myMessage = function() {
        return document.getElementById('myMessage').value;
    });

    $scope.$watch(myMessage() , function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log("myMessage changed to: " + newValue);
    });
});
```

Implemented this way, on each digest cycle, the AngularJS framework invokes the `myMessage()` function to check the value and, when the value changes, calls the handler function with the new value.

Comment: .. With this also it is just called once while the controller loads. It not called again..  I tried this..

Comment: What is the browser event that changes the element's value? You can use that event to trigger a digest cycle -- `$timeout(function(){$scope.$apply()});`. Or use `$interval` to periodically invoke a digest cycle.